# probability for full house and other combinations in bet on poker game

Tags: probability, poker

We are trying to calculate probabilities(and odds) for "bet on poker" game on which we are working now.
To calculate probabilities and odds for each hand we used https://github.com/cookpete/poker-odds library.
Now, having probabilities of  "**Royal Flush,Straight Flush, Four of a kind, Full house, Flush, Straight, Three of kind, Two pairs, One pair, High card**"  for each hand we are trying to calculate the same probabilities for entire table (for example we need probability that the winning combination of the table will be Royal flush) [in this image we have probabilities of each hand but not for entire table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqca9.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Please include all of the relevant information to your question in the statement and explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: The question of what the probability is that at a table of n players the winning hand is of a certain type seems heavily dependent on case work and unfeasible to do even by brute force.   I suggest to be satisfied instead with running simulations and approximating the probabilities with them.

Comment: thank You @JMoravitz, Your comment helped me :)  running simulations and approximating the probabilities was the best solution for me.